# Finding the eigenvalue and eigenspace for a function defined as the intersection of element of A and B

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra

Let $S$ be a non empty set and let $V_S$ be the set of all the subsets of $S$.

$V_S=\{A:A⊂S\}$

Now fix an element $B$ of $V_S$ and define a function $f:V_S \rightarrow V_S$ by $f(A)=A∩B$. Find the eigenvalues and eigenspaces of $f$.

Comment: Perhaps it would help to clarify this question.  For instance, what is $S$?  Do you want all subsets or subspaces?  If $Vs$ is a set of subsets, it's not necessarily a linear space.  Do you want $f:Vs\rightarrow Vs$?

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Typically "eigen-values" and "eigen-vectors" are associated to linear transformations on a vector space. Your question does not seem to deal with that, so perhaps you can also define these terms in your setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the power set may be regarded as a vector space over the field $F_2$, by identifying each subset with its indicator function. addition is the *exclusive* **or** operation (symmetric difference), for which the identity is the empty set, and with each set  being its own additive inverse (characteristic 2).

in this setup subset means subspace. the intersection with a fixed set is thus a projection operator which can take only the eigenvalues 0 or 1. perhaps you can identify the corresponding eigenspaces?

Comment: Thank you so much David !! Can I know how you know that addition is the exclusive or operation (symmetric difference) in this question ?

Comment: if you think of the components of a vector as elements of $F_2$ (so each is 0 or 1) the addition table is $0+0=0; 0+1=1+0=1;1+1=0$

Comment: @DavidHolden Can the power set still be a vector space over some other field that have more than 2 elements?